# Use Java Regex to find multiple matching words in a sentence

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have a sentence, and a set of words say; Mayweather, undefeated … etc.
I want to:

1. check if the sentence contains any of the above mentioned words… (I want it to look for matching words only, basically ignore full-stops, commas and new lines.)
2. and if it does, I want to display few words before and after each matching word, maybe by using `String.format()`

Here’s my code which seems to be working OK but not exactly how I want it:

```
String sentence = "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American professional boxer " +
            "currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division world champion, " +
            "having won ten world titles and the lineal championship in four different weight classes.";

    String newText = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Mayweather) .* (undefeated)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);

    if (m.find()) {
        String group1 = m.group(1);
        String group2 = m.group(2);

        newText = String.format("%s ... %s" , group1, group2);
        System.out.println(newText);
    }
```

The output now is:

> Mayweather ... undefeated

What I want is something like this:

> Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American ... currently undefeated as a professional ...

Can you please let me know how to do it, or guide me to the right direction cuz I’m stuck.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Why not use `contains()` to check and `replaceAll()` to replace?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I don't want to replace the text in the sentence, I want to display the same but in a certain way. If you meant something else, please clarify it or show me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to solve this via RegEx, you need to make your capturing groups match all that you want to output. Currently they match only your search terms:

```
(Mayweather) .* (undefeated)
// "Mayweather", "undefeated"
```

You could try something like this (using only one group!), but that would match your whole example:

```
(.*Mayweather.*undefeated.*)
// -whole text-
```

Which could be changed to this, to match the two parts again and at most 12 characters before and after (do not use spaces around the "match all" in the middle and make it non-greedy!):

```
(.{0,12}Mayweather.{0,12}).*?(.{0,12}undefeated.{0,12})
// "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an Am", "r currently undefeated as a profes"
```

Which could be further refined to stop at word boundaries (result will need to be trimmed):

```
(\b.{0,12}Mayweather.{0,12}\b).*?(\b.{0,12}undefeated.{0,12}\b)
// "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an ", " currently undefeated as a "
```

Changing this to output a fixed number of words is left as an exercise for the bored reader.

**EDIT:** Fixed greediness of ".*" in last two versions (added "?").

Comment: It seems to be working mate, thanks.. There is a tiny thing left, If I decide to show the rest of the sentence in the second match how can I do that e.g. _"Floyd Mayweather Jr is an ", " currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division world champion, having won ...."_

Comment: @M_Y You could use `undefeated.*` in that case to match the rest of the string. Or `undefeated[^.]*\.`, if you are sure your sentence ends with a period.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Your answer is much better than the one below. Your answer is accepted.

Comment: I have a slight problem with the method above mate and maybe it is a simple thing.. let's say I used "(\\b.{0,15} Mayweather.{0,15}\\b).*? (\\b.{0,15} undefeated.*)" it works fine in the above sentence and the output is "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an ... currently undefeated as a ....", but if there is another sentence which matches same words but "undefeated" comes before "Mayweather" then it doesn't display anything!! Any idea how I can fix this mate?

Comment: You could try try to match each variation, i.e. `A...B` and `B..A`. Maybe it would work with `(?:A|B)...(?:A|B)`, but that would also match "...undefeated...undefeated...".

Answer (score 0):

You can try below one ,

**Note :This is just a prototype ,So just don't copy and paste it directly**

```
String str="Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American professional boxer currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division world champion, having won ten world titles and the lineal championship in four different weight classes.";
    int firstIndex=str.indexOf("American");
    int secondIndex=str.indexOf("boxer");
    String group1=str.substring(0,firstIndex+"American".length()); // gives you 1st group

    String group2=str.substring(secondIndex);
    String newText = String.format("%s ... %s" , group1, group2);
    System.out.println(newText);
```

Output

> Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American ... boxer currently undefeated as a
>   professional and is a five-division world champion, having won ten
>   world titles and the lineal championship in four different weight
>   classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate.. I just tried your code and it works fine when the word is at the beginning of the sentence, but if the word is at the end or near the end of a long sentence then that causes a problem.. e.g. if I choose "world" and "championship" from the above sentence then it shows all the text from the beginning of the sentence i.e. "Floyd Mayweather Jr..." and what i want is it to display few words before it.. I'll try to play around with it from my end and if you have another solution let me know and I'll accept your answer. Thanks again mate.

Comment: @M_Y , told you it's only a prototype , Main catch in this logic is to find out indexes to create groups , you can/should improve this logic !! and  I have kept the index as `0`  just as example you can use whatever you want !!

Answer (score 0):

***The issue with your code lies in the use of groups.***
Regex groups provide the string snippets which you are trying to identify in the first place.

group(0), also written as group = the entire string.

group(1) is your first match = first instance of "Mayweather".

group(2) is your second match = first instance of "undefeated".

You can use the **start(int group) and end(int group) methods** to *find the indices of your matches*, and then perform some basic string operations onto a new string.

**If you intend on using Regex specifically, your solution would be as follows:**

```
      String sentence = ("Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American professional boxer " +
                  "currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division                         world champion, " +
                  "having won ten world titles and the lineal championship in four      different weight classes.");

     /** Creates a StringBuilder, which can be altered, 
     *   unlike a string, which is immutable. */
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());

     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Mayweather) .* (undefeated)");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);

     if (m.find()) {
         int g1Start = m.start(1);
         int g1End = m.end(1);

         int g2Start = m.start(2);
         int g2End = m.end(2);

         sb.append(sentence.substring(0, g1Start));
         sb.append("...");
         sb.append(sentence.substring(g1End, g2Start));
         sb.append("...");
         sb.append(sentence.substring(g2End, (sentence.length() - 1)));
```

*and I'm not sure if you needed a newline char at the end, but if so:*

```
         sb.append("\r\n");
```

*Then the rest is simple:*

```
         newText = sb.toString();
         textView.setText(newText);
     }
```

Hope this helps :)