# Check a string order in a sentence

Tags: java, string

I want to find out if a specific word comes before another. Partial words are not a match.

Some example tests:

> “Hi my name is AB, I’m from London and I love it here ..."

```
if "from" is before "Hi" -> return false
if "Hi" is before "AB" -> return true
```

Comment: `string.matches("Hi.*AB");`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-

Comment: Use a regex: `"Hi my name is AB, ...".matches(".*Hi.*AB.*")` - note the leading and trailing `.*` which is necessary because `matches()` tries to match the _entire_ string.

Comment: The basic quesion would be: what do you want to achieve? How would you handle different input, e.g. "I'm from London and I say Hi. My name is AB and I love my city. ..."?

Comment: Do you care if its an entire word?  For example do you want Hi to match the word High?  I would think no, but its an unstated requirement if so.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks mate.. I just want to know which word is mentioned first in each sentence. And you're right, I 'm looking for a general statement that can compare two words in a sentence i.e. which one is mentioned first.

Comment: @Carlos Bribiescas Yes, I'm looking for the entire word.

Comment: That invalidates all of the answers so far :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourString.matches(".*? Hi\\b.*? AB\\b.*")
```

This will make sure that you have spaces in between and you're matching whole words.

If you're dealing with latin american stuff where puncuation can come before words, this is more general

```
yourString.matches(".*?\\bHi\\b.*?\\bAB\\b.*")
```

Breaking that down you have

```
.*? = anything, even the empty string.  Ignore the ? for now.
\\b = a word boundary
```

So that regex means

`<anything><word boundary>Hi<word boundary><anything><word boundary>AB<word boundary><anything>`

which is the same as

```
if "Hi" is before "AB" -> return true
```

which would be used as

```
if(yourString.matches(".*?\\bHi\\b.*?\\bAB\\b.*")){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how can I use it. Thanks mate

Comment: Thank you very much mate.. I have a slight problem though, I have some sentences not showing up.. I think it's when one word is found before the other.. The method that I'm using is in this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603520/use-java-regex-to-find-multiple-matching-words-in-a-sentence) If you look at the link, I want it to display the found text even if one word is found before the other... please let me know how can I fix it.. it could be very simple but I'm not familiar with RegEx

Comment: If you give me the sentence that would probably be easier

Comment: I have many sentences mate lol.. as an example, you can use the same sentence used in the link which is "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an American professional boxer, currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division world champion, having won ten world titles and the lineal championship in four different weight classes."

Comment: And what are you trying to match to that sentence?

Comment: I think this is the problem, let's say I used "(\\b.{0,15} Mayweather.{0,15}\\b).*? (\\b.{0,15} undefeated.*)" it works fine in the above sentence and the output is "Floyd Mayweather Jr is an ... currently undefeated as a ....", but if there is another sentence which matches same words but "undefeated" comes before "Mayweather" then it doesn't display anything!!

Comment: Thats a slightly different question.  Yes, the regex check in a way that order matters.  If you want to check if a sentence contains two words then you could do it with X regexes each matching "\\bsomeNewWord\\b".  Also in your example that would match "MerriMayWeatherFeather".  You need the "\\b" directly around the word you're trying to match.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of doing this:

- **Use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))** - this is perhaps the simplest approach. Get indexes of the strings, and compare them. The string with a lower indexs is before the other string
- **Use regular expressions** - construct a regex that matches the strings in the desired order, for example `"from.*?Hi"`. This approach is likely to use multiple regular expressions.

One twist on the first approach would be to start searching for the second word at the index of the first word plus the length of the word, and avoid index comparisons. With many searches and long strings this could save you some CPU cycles.

**Note:** Depending on the requirements you may need to watch out for the [*Scunthorpe problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), when you get a false positive for a match on a substring. If your requirement is that `"Hi, my friend AB"` should be matched, but `"Higher than AB"` should not be matched, then the regex approach with `\b` anchors on both ends of the word would provide an easier solution than manipulating string indexes. The  `"from.*?Hi"` regex above becomes  `"\\bfrom\\b.*?\\bHi\\b"`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for a comment! You are right, false positives may be a concern. I added a note to explain this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for the answer mate.. I'm not sure if I can but I wish I can accept multiple answers so I can accept your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`indexOf(String string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-), which returns an integer denoting the position of the substring, or -1 if not found. You could use that to see which strings preceeds another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` method and get the first occurrence of each word and then check. For example:

```
String sentence = "Hi my name is AB, I’m from London and I love it here …";

int fromIndex = sentence.indexOf("from");
int hiIndex = sentence.indexOf("Hi");

if (fromIndex < hiIndex)
    System.out.println("false");
else
    System.out.println("true");
```

Note that if a word does not exist within the sentence, then `indexOf` will return `-1`.